# Title overlapping on icon in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to add `BottomNavigationView` with big icons. However, it is showing with title overlapping on icon.

Code:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemIconSize="50dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>
```

I am using version 1.0.0 of material library.

[image]

Comment: What about if you make android:layout_height="wrap_content"?

Comment: Do you want to set fix height of bottomNavigationView? and after you want solution?

Comment: @AIMINPAN It shows icons clipped to bottom.

Comment: @DPrince I want to show big icons and title below them.

Comment: @MalwinderSingh Problem is in your icon. Check if it has extra space

Comment: @MalwinderSingh if you want to give icon size then use Vector Drawable icons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in dimens.xml:

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">80dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use **`android:layout_gravity="bottom"`** and also `wrap_content` :

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
  android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
  app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

Please do not use `app:itemIconSize="70dp"`.

Reference Link :

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomNavigationView.md

Comment: remove padding also

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
            android:splitMotionEvents="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_view_color_change"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_view_color_change"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

in menu item

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home_tab"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation_home"
        android:title="@string/home"/>
```

drawable --> @drawable/bottom_view_color_change

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/selected_color" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="@color/disable_Color" android:state_checked="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use the below code.**

*For Widget Design BottomNavigationView*

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_items_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_items_color"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

*For Material Design BottomNavigationView*

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Main content -->

  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
      app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
      app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Use the below method to fixed the size of bottom navigation Icon you want.

```
private void bottomIconLarge() {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View iconView = menuView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.icon);
            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = iconView.getLayoutParams();
            final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            layoutParams.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 42, displayMetrics);
            layoutParams.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 42, displayMetrics);
            iconView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using `ConstraintLayout` as parent.

Comment: Then use app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" insted of layout_gravity. @MalwinderSingh

Comment: If you want to use your given size and it has been fixed by you, then I have a code to use the code that you can customize the icon size.

Comment: issue is not that icons are not appearing large. issue is that icons are getting cut at bottom and titles are overlapping respective icons.

Comment: Can you show your @menu/bottom_navigation_menu file

Comment: Where is bottom_navigation_menu file?